# Aurelia Two Way Binding Text Field Not Working

Tags: aurelia

Two way binding seems to not update the view unless you type in a text field. So I am using a vanilla date picker (rome). Like most date pickers it pops up a calendar to select your date.

Problem:

- Once you click a date from the date picker it will properly place the
  date in the text box. It does not however update the two-way binding.
  But if I manually type a date in the text box the two binding works
  properly and is reflected up to schedule.html

**schedule.html**

```html
<template>
  <require from="../../shared/components/date-range-picker"></require>
  <require from="../../shared/components/time-range-picker"></require>
  <div>${data.dateTime.openDate}</div> <!-- This doesn't update -->
  <date-range-picker containerless date-range.two-way="data.dateTime"></date-range-picker>
  <time-range-picker containerless time-range.two-way="data.dateTime"></time-range-picker>
</template>
```

**date-range-picker.html**

```html
<template>
  <div class="form-group input-button-group input-group date">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="open" value.bind="dateRange.openDate" class="form-control"
      placeholder="Select a Start Date" />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-ion-calendar"></i></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group input-button-group input-group date">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="close" value.bind="dateRange.closeDate" class="form-control"
      placeholder="Select a Close Date" />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-ion-calendar"></i></span>
  </div>
</template>
```

**date-range-picker.js**

```js
import { bindable, bindingMode } from 'aurelia-framework';
import rome from 'rome';
import 'rome/dist/rome.css';

export class DateRangePicker {
  @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) dateRange;

  attached() {
    const open = document.getElementById('open');
    const close = document.getElementById('close');

    rome(open, {
      time: false,
      dateValidator: rome.val.beforeEq(close),
    });

    rome(close, {
      time: false,
      dateValidator: rome.val.afterEq(open),
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could dispatch the `change` event of the input element. I've done this using a customAttribute, but you can still use customElements. Like this:

**rome.js**

```js
import {inject} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';
import {customAttribute} from 'aurelia-templating';

@inject(Element)
@customAttribute('rome')
export class Rome {

  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  attached() {
    let picker = rome(this.element);
    picker.on('data', () => {
      this.element.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    });
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```html
<require from='./rome'></require>

<input type="text" rome value.bind="selectedDate">
${selectedDate}
```

Comment: I made the changes but the bind still doesn't happen.

Comment: Nevermind got it to work now what to do if they are null

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand your question. Could you explain better?

Comment: If you have a pre-populate date and time in the text box and then click to change is where it doesn't update. Your fix worked great on that part. But you fix throws an error when/if the text box is empty. `Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined`

Comment: It seems fine to me https://gist.run/?id=c32f322b1f56e6f0a83679512247af7b. Can you reproduce the error in this Gist?